# How to extract caller Id picture from Gmail contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I want to extract friend's caller Id picture which I had on my Android phone, and synced with my Gmail account. However I lost my phone. Now the Gmail contact is showing the caller Id picture, but when tried to "save image as..." is can save only low resolution thumbnail.

Need to know procedure to download or open the actual image with full resolution as was there in phone caller Id.

Answer (score 1):

Smartphones could merge contact information from several sources like Twitter, Facebook, WhatsApp. If the Google Contact web app doesn't have the contact image with the desired resolution look to the other services that could be the original source for your contact photo.